# Extending fields doesn't create database columns in OctoberCMS

Tags: laravel-5, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I'm trying to extend backend user fields in octobercms but after adding a new field if I try to save the form there's an error says that this field doesn't exist in database. So how can add a column for my new field?
Here's my code:

```
public function boot()
{
    // Extend all backend form usage
    Event::listen('backend.form.extendFields', function($widget) {

        // Only for the User controller
        if (!$widget->getController() instanceof \Backend\Controllers\Users) {
            return;
        }

        // Only for the User model
        if (!$widget->model instanceof \Backend\Models\User) {
            return;
        }

        // Add an extra birthday field
        $widget->addTabFields([
            'birthday' => [
                'label'   => 'Birthday',
                'comment' => 'Select the users birthday',
                'type'    => 'datepicker',
                'tab'     => 'Billing'
            ]
        ]);


    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Extending a model will not automatically create the fields in the database for you.

To create database fields, you need to create a [migration](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/structure) and then run it.

The [Builder Plugin](http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-builder) offers a very nice way of graphically creating, applying and rolling back migrations.

Comment: @Ahmed Essam: I must point out that adding migrations directly to somebody else's plugin that you don't control is just asking for trouble. See https://vimeo.com/108040919 for a tutorial on how to take care of this problem.